# UWP ListView Button MVVM Binding

Tags: c#, listview, mvvm, uwp

I have a `ListView` that, right now opens a Popup on `SelectedItem`. 
What I want is that if the user decides to remove an Item from the List he can click the Button and it gets removed - right now the Button does fire, but how do I tell the Button in the VM what Item to delete - without "SelectedItem"?  p.E..

```
<ListView 
 SelectedItem="{Binding...}"
 x:Name="lv">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <Image Source="{Binding...}"/>
                <Button Command="{Binding ElementName=lv,Path=DataContext.RemoveXCommand}" />
            </Stackpanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

VM

```
public void RemoveXCommand()
    {
    foreach(var item in pseudo)
       {
       if(item.Name == ?????)
           pseudo.Remove(item);
       }
    }
```

Is there a way, or do I have to remove the opening of the Popup, and implement it as another Button, so I can use the SelectedItem to get the comparison?

Thank you.

EDIT1:

Thanks to [Fruchtzwerg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5235574/fruchtzwerg) I got it working

```
public RelayCommand<string> RemoveXCommand{ get; private set; }

//... in then Constructor
RemoveXCommand = new RelayCommand<string>((s) => RemoveXCommandAction(s));

public void RemoveXCommand(object temp)
{
foreach(var item in pseudo)
   {
   if(item.Name == (string) temp)
       pseudo.Remove(item);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the item you need to remove as `CommandParameter`

```
<Button Command="{Binding ElementName=lv, Path=DataContext.RemoveXCommand}"
        CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
```

and remove it like

```
public void RemoveXCommand(object itemToRemove)
{
    pseudo.Remove(itemToRemove);
}
```

Your approach deleting the item by name is also possible. Bind the `Name` of the item as `CommandParameter`

```
<Button Command="{Binding ElementName=lv, Path=DataContext.RemoveXCommand}"
        CommandParameter="{Binding Name}"/>
```

and remove it like

```
public void RemoveXCommand(object nameToRemove)
{
    foreach(var item in pseudo)
    {
        if(item.Name == (string)nameToRemove)
        {
            pseudo.Remove(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Note that the second approach is removing all items having the name of the item you selected. The first approach removes only the item you selected because the specific instance is removed.

To allow a parameter in `RelayCommand` a new or modified implementeation of `ICommand` is required. Here is a possible solution:

```
public class ParameterRelayCommand : ICommand
{
    private readonly Action<object> _execute;
    private readonly Func<bool> _canExecute;

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public ParameterRelayCommand(Action<object> execute)
        : this(execute, null)
    { }

    public ParameterRelayCommand(Action execute<object>, Func<bool> canExecute)
    {
        if (execute == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("execute");
        _execute = execute;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return _canExecute == null ? true : _canExecute();
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _execute(parameter);
    }

    public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
    {
        var handler = CanExecuteChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If i try this I get an error in my constructor (where i init. my command) "Conversion from Method to Action not possible (translated.)) at `RemoveXCommand = new RelayCommand(RemoveXCommandAction)`

Comment: This is because `RelayCommand` does not implement parameter. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33003207/universal-windows-platform-commanding-with-parameters you need to modify `RelayCommand` by adding the object parameter to the action in constructor

Comment: So do I have to switch RelayCommand with ICommand and how do I add the parameter in the constructor? ty.

Comment: I've added the code of the `ParameterRelayCommand`. You could take this class to create the commands. Simply use `ParameterRelayCommand` instead of `RelayCommand` if you need to pass a parameter.

Comment: `_execute`is readonly and later you set `_execute = execute`? This gets me confused, but I got it working thanks to you.

Comment: Correct, this was a typo - i fixed it.